# IIS Url Rewrite results in 403 Forbidden

Tags: html, iis, url-rewriting, url-routing, http-status-code-403

**UPDATE**

After enabling direcorty listing it seems to have worked but now im running into another error.

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html
```

I'm trying to rewrite a URL to take content from the absolute directory.

Let's assume my URL was https://somesite.com/a  <--  absolute path 
 
This directory consist of files like `index.html, contact.html` and folders like `css,js,img`

But i want to access this directory with a `URL` like 
`https://somesite.com/a/somename/index` which should take me to 
`https://somesite.com/a/index` 
 but it should also keep the parameter `somename` in the URL therefore redirecting is not an option, this is because i  need to use the `Referrer Url` later onwards from backend code.

**My Rule**

```
<rule name="StoreRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^a/([^/]+)/([^/]+)" />
         <conditions>
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
         <action type="Rewrite" url="a/{R:2}" />
 </rule>
```

The above redirect works but it doesn't load the additional content inside the html files, 
 like `js,css` files which are all relative to the html file.

The below error is show when i enter the url `https://somesite.com/a/someprofile/contact` 
The page from `a\contact` is displayed but not its relative content.
The console is filled with this error

```
  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

[image: The above is shown when i enter the URL]

Comment: find the http sub-status code for the 403s in the http logs on the IIS server and add it to your question. When using rewrite or redirect using relative links in the page becomes tricky.

Comment: make sure that static content role is installed.and check that you give full control to  IIS_IUSRS and IUSR to access site folder.try to add authorization for all the folders that contained the CSS, JS and images.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Static content is installed and yes all the authorization stuff is done. It works when i access it with the normal url.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf After looking into the sub status code 14 i fixed it by enabling direcotry browsing on iis. But now i run into another error for the CSS and JS files as thier content type is set to text/html. Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://autodevserver.com/a/vendor/"

Comment: in iis setting check that .css extension has text/css mime type [image link](https://i.postimg.cc/HLxWQXtD/css.jpg) or not.also check response header has Content-Type: text/css.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631158/resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-see/34669257) .